# Storm water Geometric Network Tracing Catch Basins

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geometric-network, utility-network-analyst

I am using ArcGis 10.3 and am trying to trace a geometric network from a catch basin to a catch basin lead to a mainline ultimately to a storm pond.

1. Flow direction is set correctly using digitized direction
2. Traces when the flag is placed at the mainline manhole, the tracing works flawlessly
3. Problem occurs when I trace from a catch basin, it will highlight to the lead by stop at the mainline, what could I be missing?

My mainline and CB leads are in the same feature class.
CB points and manholes are in the same point feature class.

CB and MH Points:Simple Junction

Mainline and CB Leads fc: Complex Edge

[image: EXAMPLE]

Comment: Did you try [rebuilding connectivity](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geometric-networks/about-repairing-network-connectivity.htm#GUID-37DB2010-8977-44B3-87E5-3825DB1EDD66)?

Comment: Newly built network with no new edits, but I will give that a shot.

Comment: Did not work the same problem persists

Comment: What type of junction feature is located where the tracing stops ? Is it enabled?

Comment: Connecting a line to a line (as shown above) 
Enabled: Yes (TRUE)

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, I needed to add a junction to the line where it attaches to the mainline.